# Angular module test not working

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, karma-runner

I am trying to test an angularjs app. I managed to get some basic test running on my laptop. These tests just check for a module and check some basic functions. This works fine on my laptop. However when I move the testing environment to a local server the tests stop working. For example regardless of what module name I pass in the test still passes. I haven't tried testing any functions yet. Just a module test.

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('mcqsApp', []);
```

simpleTest.js:

```
describe('SimpleService test', function(){
    beforeEach(function(){
        module('blah');
    });

    it('SimpleService should have a module',function(){

    });
});
```

karma.conf.js:

```
module.exports = function(config){
config.set({
    //  root path location that will be used to resolve all relative paths in files and exclude sections, should be the root of your project
    basePath : '../',

    // files to include, ordered by dependencies
    files : [
        // include relevant Angular files and libs
        'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js',
        'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-mocks.js',

        // include js files
        '../../../public/js/app.js',

        '../../../public/js/services/*/*.js',

        // include unit test specs
        'test/unit/services/*.js'
    ],
    // files to exclude
    exclude : [

    ],

    // karma has its own autoWatch feature but Grunt watch can also do this
    autoWatch : true,

    // testing framework, be sure to install the karma plugin
    frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai'],

    // browsers to test against, be sure to install the correct karma browser launcher plugin
    browsers : ['PhantomJS'],

    // progress is the default reporter
    reporters: ['mocha'],

    // map of preprocessors that is used mostly for plugins
    preprocessors: {

    },

    // list of karma plugins
    plugins : [
        'karma-junit-reporter',
        'karma-chrome-launcher',
        'karma-firefox-launcher',
        'karma-mocha',
        'karma-chai',
        'karma-sinon',
        'karma-mocha-reporter',
        'karma-phantomjs-launcher'
    ]
})}
```

It is my understanding that this should fail if the module names do not match. But this test will pass regardless of the module name. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you guys need o see any more code such as my karma.conf.js file just ask and I will make an update.

Comment: Your karma.conf would be nice

Comment: updated with karma.conf

Comment: First thing to fix: use the same version for angular and angular-mocks.

Comment: @JBNizet done now they are both 1.3.15. Still passing with an incorrect module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that I was not loading in the appropriate bower_components into the karma.conf.js. Changing to the un-minified version of angular allowed me to see the more descriptive errors which helped me solve this.